# preg_match or preg_match_all to find all words in string with anything between them

Tags: preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to find all words in a string.
The user can add words in any pattern like comma seperated or ; seperated or anything.

**Input:** Hello, Hi, test word
**Output:** array("Hello","Hi","test","word");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a word is string that contains only word characters `\w`, you could do:

```
preg_match_all('/(\w+)/', $input_string, $matches);
```

Or use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$words = preg_split('/\W+/', $input_string);
```